# FirebaseAuthException thrown although it is caught

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, exception

I'm trying to build a firebase login function, but the code crashes even though the exception thrown is caught.

When I output the exception as a log the code works, but when I pass it on as an exception it crashes.

I would like to pass the exception on to the MainActivity in order to process it correctly there, i.e. to have the exception.message output there as toast.

The login process works with the use of valid login data without problems only if firebase reports an exception it crashes.

```
internal var loginResult = MutableLiveData<LoginResult>()
```

```
inner class LoginResult {
        var authResult: AuthResult? = null
        var exception: Exception? = null
        var isSuccessful = false

        constructor(authResult: AuthResult?, isSuccessful: Boolean) {
            this.authResult = authResult
            this.isSuccessful = isSuccessful
        }
        
        constructor(authResult: AuthResult?, exception: Exception?, isSuccessful: Boolean) {
            this.authResult = authResult
            this.exception = exception
            this.isSuccessful = isSuccessful
        }
    }
```

```
fun login(context: Context, email: String, password: String) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    loginResult.value = LoginResult(task.result, task.isSuccessful)
                    startSession(context, LoginType.CREDENTIAL)
                    saveCredentialsEncrypted(context, email, password)
                } else {
                    try {
                        loginResult.value = LoginResult(task.result, task.exception, task.isSuccessful)
                    } catch (e: FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        loginResult.value = LoginResult(task.result, e, task.isSuccessful)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        loginResult.value = LoginResult(task.result, e, task.isSuccessful)
                    }

                }
            }
    }
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.simplesaakotlin, PID: 23984
    com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:15)
        at com.example.simplesaakotlin.auth.AuthManager$login$1.onComplete(AuthManager.kt:84)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.tasks.zzb.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:6)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztt.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:28)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvc.zzk(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuz.zzh(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztq.zzk(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzoi.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvg.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuq.zzf(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzpy.zzj(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztu.zzi(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzsk.zzd(Unknown Source:15)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzsj.accept(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zach.doExecute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.3.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zah.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.3.0:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zac(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.3.0:192)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.3.0:157)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.3.0:125)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.3.0:144)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.base.zap.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.3.0:8)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

UPDATE:
the error was thrown because i tried to access the task.result when there was no result, see the try catch block.

To fix this error i passed null as authResult

```
 fun login(context: Context, email: String, password: String) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    loginResult.value = LoginResult(task.result, task.isSuccessful)
                    startSession(context, LoginType.CREDENTIAL)
                    saveCredentialsEncrypted(context, email, password)
                } else {
                    loginResult.value = LoginResult(null, task.exception, task.isSuccessful)
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but sometimes is because you copy paste your password or email to edittext and do not see has space in it, like "test@gmail.com" to become "test@gmail.com  "

Comment: I am expecting this exception when i pass the values, i dont know why this exception getting thrown without even getting called to s.th. i am only passing it through

Comment: I am intentionally passing the wrong credentials to get an exception but i only want to pass it and not throw it

Comment: Are you sure you have a password? If yes, is it really correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the FirebaseAuthException was not thrown/caught in Debug mode. But it worked fine in Relase mode.